# Refactoring a data class in C++

Tags: c++, class, refactoring

So I have the following class which I find silly and would like to refactor.

```
class Data
{
  public:
    bool getVariableA();
    bool getVariableB();
    bool getVariableC();

    void setVariableA();
    void setVariableB();
    void setVariableC();

  private:
    bool A;
    bool B;
    bool C;
}
```

This goes on for like 100 variables and growing, most of which are boolean. If you were to refactor this class (while keeping all the data in it instead of spreading out), how would you go about it?

Issues with the current structure are at least that it's a) too much code b) pain to add stuff c) unit testing coverage always needs to be added manually when growing the class.

Comment: *"This goes on for like 100 variables and growing, most of which are boolean."* - use an array or map, why have 100 different variable names?

Comment: Array/map and some enum was what I had also in mind but wanted to see if there was some other way I didn't know about.

Comment: @JonnyHenly pardon my ignorance but what is in the scope of stackoverflow and what belongs to programmers?

Comment: hmm I thought stackoverflow's ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) mentioned something about programmers.stackexchange but apparently I was wrong. Although taking a look at programmers' ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), it becomes clear that [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) is a better fit for this type of question. I would just leave it here though, I don't think it's breaking any rules : )

Comment: I would, at the very least, delete all the getters and setters and make it a `struct` to indicate aggregate data. The *vector/map* solutions look attractive too. The *map* may yield special benefits if only a few variables out of the many possible variables are usually needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how would you go about it?

The solution proposed by @JohnHenly is spot-on:

I would use this code:

```
std::vector<bool> data;
enum index { var_a, var_b, var_c, ... };

data[var_a] = true;
```

If possible though, consider also splitting the data by one of these criteria:

- logical group
- location where they are used
- purpose

Answer (score 2):

First you must rethink your class design. Your class should have single responsibility as per the best practices. So if you have lots of member variables then your class might be handling more than one responsibility.
For refactoring you can extract more classes from this class. This means you can group related variables and functionality into another class and use it. For example if have some variables like,

```
bool isNetworkConnected;
bool isNetworkReachable;
int networkSpeed;
string networkName;
```

In this case you can create a new class named `NetworkInformation` and then declare a single class variable like,

```
NetworkInformation networkInfo;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, good answer. However, in this particular case they are actually already in the right class. There can be many events received from a system component and this class stores the status of those. It could be split to many but if the same structure would remain it would not really solve it.